# flash player - random behaviour - slow video play

Tags: flash

i use xubuntu 16.04 and i have problem with playing videos from youtube, southpark.cc.com and so on..

when my system is up there is a chance that every video that i stream is slow in firefox and chrome as well.

it could happen that everything works fine in one session, and than after restart i have problem again, and if i restart yet another time it could work well, but it could work slow too..

it is very weird and i do not know what spell to cast.

thanks
: )

Comment: Youtube default is HTML5, not Flash, since a long time ago; Southpark uses Flash. However, it's unlikely to be a Flash related issue because Chrome (not Chromium) ships with the latest Adobe Flash so it shouldn't be a problem. It isn't, I just tested. I could be internet connection issues (consistent with the intermittent nature of the problem) and/or graphics issues. Please define "slow"...

Comment: hi,it is not network issue. the same computer works like a charm in windows (dual boot), or in xubuntu if restarted and if in that session video streaming is ok. youtube or southpark videos are played *when xubuntu behave bad* like in 50% speed, women voices sound like a drung men voices and so on... thanks for the interest :)

Comment: .. the same problem i have with play of google-photos videos (on both browsers)

Comment: the same thing - slow motion play and disordered sounds - i have with the chromium as well (i've tried this browser too)